# CentOS 5.7 Apache to Read The Files Inside public_html

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd

I just finished installing apache to my server. If I access the website, the apache 2 test page will appear informing that the installation is success.

Then I put my websites under public_html. But the apache still don't access the public_html folder.

This is my first experience using linux as my OS server.

Answer (score 1):

The apache default root under centos is usually the path `/var/www/`. If you want to change it to `public_html`, you need to edit your server config and possibly use virtual hosts.

Comment: How to change the path ? Is it in httpd.conf ?

Comment: You can look for `DocumentRoot` in your httpd.conf file. I recommend you to read about this more before unless you don't mind to break your server.